# Jenkins build logs are too large

Tags: linux, jenkins, solaris

I have some jobs in Jenkins that create logs that are 300MB large, each.
The build's log gets created on my Solaris M6 machine.

Fact : I cannot pimp my job because of a business process, it must stay as it is.

> My question : How to maintain such huge logs?
>
> Is there any way that Jenkins perhaps knows how to ZIP the logs by
>   himself and then UNZIP it when my user tries to read the Console
>   Output (the logs itself via Jenkins) ?

Because if I zip the log manually on Solaris, it will no longer be readable via Jenkins.

Comment: Just an update if someone has the same issue:

There is a Jenkins Plugin that compresses (gzip) the logs and they uncompress on the fly as soon as a users wants to read it via Jenkins.

Link to a plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Compress+Build+Log+Plugin

Comment: Can you post-process the logs, remiving lines from some whitelist with a command like `grep -vf remove-from-logfiles.txt` ?

Comment: If you need to compress the logs and don't want to be limited to only using Jenkins to read them, you can use a file system with native compression.  On Solaris, ZFS is an obvious option.  You just need root access to set up a compressed ZFS file system.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Hudson (Jenkins) has a support for .gz format, which means you can gzip all the logs and Jenkins will still be able to read them, which is SUPER AWESOME ! That way I saved tons of GB's of storage, it shrinked my 600MB logs to just 2MB, great.